# GeoIP с точностью до города

Tags: геолокация, php

Как можно узнать город по IP в php? Очень желательно, чтобы без запросов к сторонним сайтам (так как нужна скорость). Штатный geoIP (debian) нужную точность не дает (только страна), GeoLite City Edition тоже (для моего IP не нашел город, только страну).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только по базе ип адресов. Например, [вот](http://ipgeobase.ru/).

Comment: Просто хотелось бы такую базу получить себе на сервер.

Comment: Посмотрите, там можно скачать базу в разделе "Архив"

Answer (score 1):

[База GeoIP – страны и города, июнь 2011 (+скрипт обновления)](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/120872/).
Великая вещь - гугл.

Comment: > База распространяется в двух модификациях: «Страны и города» (21Mb, после установки ~122Mb)  и «Только страны» 2Mb, после установки ~13Mb).


мде...)

Comment: Мне кажется лучше парсить с постороннего сайта)